# sort data from one matrix by another matrix in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I am in kind of a pickle. I have multiple matrices and want to sort the first column of a matrix by the last column of the previous matrix. Any ideas? I have tried apply, order, sort, etc.

```
  ########################################################
  ######################CODE#########################
  ### makes indiviual matrix of data ##
  ## this area would be replaced by read.files
  one<-matrix(c(2001,2002,2003,2004,23456, 23567,54321,12345),4,2);
  two<-matrix(c(54321,23567,23456,12345,1234,2345,3456,7777),4,2);
  three<-matrix(c(3456,7777,2345,1234,5677,6789,6678,6767),4,2);
  four<-matrix(c(6678,5677,6767,6789,5555,1111,1112,1113),4,2);
  five<-matrix(c(5555,1113,1112,1111,2222,1212,9999,8888),4,2);

  #######order all data######################
  onea<-one[order(one[,2]),];
  twoa<-two[order(two[,1]),];
  threea<-three[order(twoa[,2]),]; ####CANT GET THIS PART TO WORK!!!!!
```

What I want to do is sort three by twoa[,2]

```
  ####output looking for: 
 cbind(onea,twoa,threea)
 [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,] 2004 12345 12345 7777 7777 6789
 [2,] 2001 23456 23456 3456 3456 5677
 [3,] 2002 23567 23567 2345 2345 6678
 [4,] 2003 54321 54321 1234 1234 6767
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Why would you expect that output? `twoa[, 2]` is in reverse order, so when you sort `threea` you will reverse the order of the rows.

Comment: Hi David, if you look at the sample code I have given the second column of one is the same as the first column of two and so forth. However the numbers will be out of order. each matrix represents a new data set. What my experiment entails is that I start with a known value, assign it a new number (one), then assign the second column of one to a new number. This would make the matrix (two). This would repeat until the end of the experiment (five). I want to trace the last column of matrix 5 and pull out the number that corresponds to the original number I started with in one[1,1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you're after, but if you are looking for the last column of each matrix to "match up" with the first column of the next, you can combine `order` and `rank` like this:

```
onea<-one[order(one[,2]),];
twoa<-two[order(two[,1])[rank(onea[,2])],];
threea<-three[order(three[,1])[rank(twoa[,2])],]
foura<-four[order(four[,1])[rank(threea[,2])],]
fivea<-five[order(five[,1])[rank(foura[,2])],]
cbind(onea,twoa,threea,foura,fivea)
##      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## [1,] 2004 12345 12345 7777 7777 6789 6789 1113 1113  1212
## [2,] 2001 23456 23456 3456 3456 5677 5677 1111 1111  8888
## [3,] 2002 23567 23567 2345 2345 6678 6678 5555 5555  2222
## [4,] 2003 54321 54321 1234 1234 6767 6767 1112 1112  9999
```

Comment: thanks mrip. This is what I wanted! I didnt know you can rank in this way.